# Review queue item disappears when navigating away from the page and then returning to it

Tags: bug, review

This is probably going to be a bit tricky to describe, so don't hesitate to ask for clarification in the comments in case I fail to do so. The problem is as follows:

When reviewing items from the review queue, if I navigate away from the item I'm reviewing for some reason (e.g. sometimes I want to see original wording, if the post was in the meantime edited by someone else), and then return back to the review of the post by using the browser's "back" button, the review item disappears. I.e. it is no longer available for review by me. This is a bit annoying, especially if you take care to read all about the item you're reviewing, only to be punished for your thoroughness in return by being disallowed to review it.

I realize I could try and maintain same location within the review window and simply follow links in a new tab or window, but breaking a habit is a difficult thing to do, so this happens to me quite frequently. It also seems odd that an item from the review queue would be marked as unavailable to the user that just *viewed* it, so I'm marking this as a bug as it might create other problems I haven't came across myself. I see how this could solve some problems like opening same item in multiple tabs / windows, but the handling doesn't seem correct to me. It should be done *on action* and not *on display* of the item.

Please see if you could change the behavior of the review queue to allow display of same item until the review by a user is completed, i.e. some required action made on it, or the "skip" button is pressed.

---

OK, as requested, I took some screengrabs. I'll explain where I was at and what I did in their caption under them, and I added UTC time for each in the light green box on the individual screen grab:

[image]

<sup>**Screen 1**: Just the usual First Post review item here. As we can see, it was already edited by another user, so let's pretend for
    the purpose of demonstrating this problem that I'm interested in what it originally looked like and I'll click the *"edited 23 minutes ago"*
    link to reveal its revision history.</sup>

[image]

<sup>**Screen 2**: I'm in the revision history now, and there's nothing too special here, just some tags added and the question was tweeted
    to the Sec.SE twitter account. I'll wait a bit on this screen, pretending it was some substantial edit and it'll take me a few minutes to
    read all its changes to the original post.</sup>

[image]

<sup>**Screen 3**: After two minutes have passed, I try navigating back to where I came from, using browser's back button. Nothing there,
    the review item has seemingly disappeared from the review queue and it looks like it was successfully handled by others in the
    meantime. Nice, no problem, if that was really the case, but...</sup>

[image]

<sup>**Screen 4**: 5 minutes later, the same review queue item actually reappears in the review queue and this time I can complete my
    review. Which I did, and those that have access to Security.SE review queue history will have means to confirm that.</sup>

I hope this makes the problem a bit clearer now. I would also like to add that this will require an answer from those that have access to current SE code, so developers themselves. It can be identified as a bug, or as "by design", since there is obviously some database locking mechanism involved here to prevent multiple concurrent / parallel updates on the same review queue item and prevent problems that could arise from it, if that was allowed, but since there are other ways of assuring concurrency, I would like an answer if I should adjust my habits to prevent such problems, or can I look forward to changes to the database locking event model of the SE review process.

Comment: I think when you leave the page, it marks the review as available for other users again, and if another user comes and reviews it while you're viewing the actual question, there's no reason to review it when you come back anymore.

Comment: But is it better to wait 10-20 minutes to see if someone comes back after leaving the review page, or is it better to let someone else review it? I often leave the review queue page just because I'm done for the moment, but don't want to skip through *all* of the remaining posts, after all, I usually come back after some time and might want to review those then, if no-one else has. Again, leaving the page is a "I'm done for now" message to me.

Comment: No bug here. By the time you get back the item was already reviewed.

Comment: Can you show example? I wasn't able to reproduce such thing.

Comment: @TildalWave which review queue (or review queues) do you see this behavior in?  That would be a start to let users try to reproduce this.

Comment: I downvoted based on the assumption that what you experience is not a bug, but rather as described in other comments just case of item already reviewed by the time you get back to it. I still can't understand what exactly you *do* experience, if you can clarify and add more details edit and I'll undo my vote. For example you can take screenshot of the page when you get back and can't review anymore.

Comment: I've confirm that this doesn't happen in the Reopen and close queues, which could explain the downvotes since no one can repo it.  Since specific examples are tough (except for the screen shot @ShadowWizard suggested) identification of the queues in the question might be beneficial as well.

Comment: @TildalWave I'm not a dev for SE and we can't know how their code looks like. There might be much more to it behind the scenes. As for bug or not, when I'll understand what you experience maybe I'll be able to judge myself. :)

Comment: @TildalWave with thousands of bug reports, we can't expect the dev team to give full attention to each and every one of them. Urgent bugs can be pushed in chat to get more immediate attention, otherwise we can bump bug reports from time to time in hope of getting authoritative attention. This specific case, even if actual bug, isn't very fatal.

Comment: @TildalWave I think I figured what's going on. When it next happens to you, please copy the full URL you have in step/screen #3 (after navigating back) - most likely you'll see `#[number]` appended to the original URL causing it to break. I still couldn't figure what caused this though. :/

Comment: @TildalWave I still don't think there's any locking involved, hopefully a dev will check this though. Remind me in a week or two if it won't happen and I'll bump this report with a bounty.

Comment: This sounds familiar... Before I try to reproduce it though, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this either, nor can I see any good reason why it would be happening to you. My best guess is that the actual ID of the review task you're viewing isn't being recorded for some reason, but that doesn't seem to be born out by the logs either.